# Setting CURRENT_DATE to constant value in Postgresql for unit testing

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, time, data-cleaning

I'm trying to write unit tests for a small script which deletes all entries older than 6 months from a PostgreSQL database table.  The script executes the following query.

```
DELETE FROM some_table WHERE tstamp < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '180 days');
```

The script is in Python and I'm using [testing.postgresql](https://github.com/tk0miya/testing.postgresql) to create a local temporary database instance that I can freely manipulate.  The issue I'm having is that I cannot find a way to force CURRENT_DATE to be a constant value so that I can create test entries that are before and after a certain date, and will not change if the test are run later in time.

Is it possible to override CURRENT_DATE in a PostgreSQL database to always return a pre-defined time?

Comment: create a function someSchema.current_date() that returns whatever, then put that schema ahead of public in your search path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot to change CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Your issue is usual, and common solution is simple - break your code between part without any these pseudoconstants and part with it.

So function/query

```
DELETE FROM some_table WHERE tstamp < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '180 days');
```

isn't testable, but function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_180days(_to_date date)
RETURNS void AS $$
  DELETE FROM some_table
    WHERE tstamp < ($1 - INTERVAL '180 days')
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Now, I can write tests for function `delete_180days`. In application I can use it `SELECT delete_180days(CURRENT_DATE)`